# How Do Sets Determine Sameness and Difference?

Tags: python

If I have a class

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

And two objects

```
bar = Foo(1, 2)
baz = Foo(1, 3)
```

How does Python determine whether or not `baz` should be added to a `set` that already holds `bar`? Is there a way to control this behaviour?

Comment: Check out the magic `__eq__` method.

Comment: Well that seems obvious now.

Comment: .. and `__hash__(..)`, too.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Yep. Forgot that one!